# Hide a div if appeared

Tags: jquery, html

I have a message box div in my page which will appear after succesfully submitting a form. I want to hide it after some time as it appears.

I have tried this code in the chrome developer tool and it works.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   if ($('#notification').is(":visible")) {
       $('#notification').delay(1000).fadeOut();
   }
});
```

But when I inserted this code to my page, its not working.

Kindly give me a solution for this.

Thank you & Regards,

Comment: Your page html will be useful here.

Answer (score 5):

you are running this code inside a dom-ready function: `$(document).ready(function(){ ...`

This means that the code will run once when the page finishes loading, and at that time the notification is probably not visible, and so the code continues and will not run this again.

you need to bind this function to run **every time the form is submitted**, using [jQuery's .submit() method](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: Thank you, Can you give me an example

Comment: this code needs to run after the notification popup is displayed.
add your if statement directly after you display `#notification`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    $('#notification').fadeIn().delay(3000).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Is there are any way to do this without using an event?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **`setTimeout`** call:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    if ($('#notification').is(":visible")) {
       $('#notification').delay(1000).fadeOut();
   }
}, 3000);
```